# drawing an X with python Turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a really simple task to draw an X in python using Turtles, but i cannot seem to understand how the setposition() method works.

my code currently draws the first line correct, but then the second line skews up too much no matter what i try.

```
t.right(45)
t.pendown()
t.setposition(50,-50)
t.penup()
t.left(90)
t.setposition(0,-50)
t.pendown()
t.setposition(50,50)
```

Comment: It would be best if you show a minimal example of what is going wrong. And also post the output image with what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line starts at `(0,0)` and got to `(50, -50)`, thus goes 50 units in **X** and **Y** direction. But you second ist going from `(0,-50)` to `(50,50)`, thus goes 50 units in **X** direction and **100 units** in **Y** direction. Additionally your right and left have no effect.

One possible solution would be:

```
t.setposition(-50,50)
t.pendown()
t.setposition(50,-50)
t.penup()
t.setposition(-50,-50)
t.pendown()
t.setposition(50,50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can take is to avoid `setposition()` altogether and think like a turtle.  That is, crawl forward, backward and turn rather than teleport:

```
import turtle as t

t.right(45)
t.forward(70)
t.backward(140)
t.forward(70)
t.left(90)
t.forward(70)
t.backward(140)

t.hideturtle()
t.done()
```